# How to change background with keyboard shortcut

Tags: source-code

What file controls the image displayed on the desktop background. And how might i go about editing it so that i can change the background by pressing a key on my keyboard (is a way to do that already?). I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: As a reputation 1 user, please consider  marking any one of the below answers that you find as the most satisfactory solution to your question by clicking the grey checkmark below up and down arrows of each post to mark the one as accepted. You can also leave the posts unmarked if you find that none of the posts provide a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way to do so is via `gsettings` command paired together with 
`zenity --file-selection` which allows you to choose a file. There are more advanced ways to do it via `python` and `python-gi` API, but a simple and short shell script is sufficient.

#### Usage

Save this script in your `~/bin` directory ( if you don't have the `bin` folder in your home folder, then create one).  Next open **System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom** and click the `+` button to create new shortcut. Make sure you give full path to the script as command, like `/home/john_doe/bin/change_background.sh` and make sure to assign a key to this shortcut by clicking on the right field

#### Script source

Please ensure that the script is made executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/change_background.sh` command in terminal  or via righ-click -> Properties menu in the GUI file manager

```
#!/bin/bash

file_path=$(zenity --file-selection)

if [ "x$file_path" != "x"  ];
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://"$file_path"
fi
```

#### Additional info

You've asked:

> What file controls the image displayed on the desktop background

Technically speaking, there is no single file specifically for background settings. There is `dconf` database for user settings ( which is typically stored in your `~/.config/dconf/user` file ).  This is binary data , so you can't simply open it in text editor and write the name of file you want to be displayed as your background. What you can do is use either `dconf` or `gsettings` command. `dconf` operates on that database directly, while `gsettings` does a few "sanity checks" for the data you put in, so it's is very common to see `gsettings` being used although in my experience there is no advantage from using one over the other, and in fact I personally prefer using `dconf`. In either case, these two tools are what I would consider are power-user tools that do the same thing.

Comment: Works great.  Were did you find the 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri' command?

Comment: It's one of the standard commands that ships with Ubuntu and any gnome-based desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri** command.  Put the `file:///[location of image]` as the parameter.

For example:

```
 $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///$HOME/Pictures/myimage.png"
```

You can also use the **gsettings get** to get the current background image.  This will show you the current background image.

```
 $ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

will show:

```
 file:///home/users/l/j/ljames/Pictures/backgrounds/myimage.png
```

**Update:**

The system stores the background image in a binary file located at:

```
$HOME/.config/dconf/user
```

**A script to show the current background would have this content:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

current_background=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri))
echo $current_background
```

When you run the script it'll show you the current pathname of the current background.

You can store your file anywhere and put the pathname in a location where your script will read the location into a variable and use that.

In  this example use a text editor to put the file's pathname in a file called background.

**Create the script and save it:**

```
$ gedit ~/bin/setbackground.sh
$ chmod +x ~/bin/setbackground.sh
```

**This is the content for the script:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

background=$(cat ~/background)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///$background"
```

**Edit the file to contain the background image to use.**

```
$ gedit $HOME/background
```

Put the path name `/home/yourID/Pictures/myimage.png` and save the file.

**Run and test the script from the commandline:**

```
$ ~/bin/setbackground.sh
```

*(note: after relogging in you can just type `setbackgrund.sh` without the path to run the script from the commandline).*

### Set the HotKey

Now you can use the Ubuntu's **keyboard settings** to set the hotkey.  Go to:

```
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts -> (click) + ->
(Type in Name and Command) -> (click) Apply
```

**Place this in the `Custom Shortcut` window:**

```
Name:       Set Background
Command:    /home/userID/setbackground.sh
```

For the keyboard shortcut you can put:

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

Now anytime you want to change your background, jut put the pathname in your $HOME/background file, then hit your keyboard hotkey to change it to that.

Comment: Can i assign "gsettings get" to a variable?

Comment: You would need to assign the key to a script to call the variable.

Comment: so if it were in a script could i write something like `current_background=gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`

Comment: Yes.  When I get back to my shop I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: @merrill4 You're welcome.  Sorry it took so long, but I updated the answer to include the clarification you asked for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49913/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-merrill4).